# Taskpane is not showing properly in Word 2016 Web Add-ins

Tags: ms-office, office365, manifest, office-js, word-web-addins

I have created an Web Add-ins project for Word using Visual Studio. 
I have Office 2016 Professional Plus installed on my system.

[image]

When I try to launch the application using F5. Everything works, but when I click on the button in the ribbon menu to show the task pane. Task pane is shown but with following error message.

> ADD-IN ERROR
>
> This add-in could not be started. Close this dialog to ignore the
>   problem or click "Restart" to try again.

**UPDATE:**

I have tried to create a new project/solution and without modifying anything. It is giving the same error on running or hitting `F5`.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have verified that I have Latest version of Office developer tools installed.
[image]

I shared the same application that I created with another colleague here and it did not run on his machine either, but when I tried to create a File->New Project on another machine (it worked there) and tried to run that on my system and it didn't work.

Comment: Hello Naveed. Will be great if you can provide mode details. For instance, do you have the latest VS Office developer tools installed?  Check our this page to get the latest.  Also provide more details of your environment, there is a rule that can be set on organizations to disable add-ins. Go to File-> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> trusted Add-in Catalogs and make sure the options Under "Truisted Web Add-ins Catalogs" are not checked.

Comment: I am sorry for the late response. The issue was on my office machine and I could not reply earlier. The Trust center settings are Correct as you mentioned. And the latest developer tools for office are also installed. `Microsoft Office Developer Tools Update 2`

Comment: Sounds like your dev environment is corrupted. I do t like to recommend this but hace you tried re-installing VS?

Comment: Thanks Juan for this support. It started working after that... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue because of a bad environment setup. After I uninstalled and then reinstalled Visual Studio, everything started working again, as suggested in [@JuanBalmori](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5904541/juan-balmori)'s comment.